# two classes inheriting from one Higher level

Tags: python, inheritance

The following code seems to append `['next']` twice to the `self.list_of`, even though its acting on two independent objects.

```
class Higher:
    def __init__(self, list_of: list = ['item1', 'item2'],):

        self.list_of=list_of

        self.list_of += ['next']


class NumberOne(Higher):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):

        super().__init__(**kwargs)


class NumberTwo(Higher):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):

        super().__init__(**kwargs)


if __name__=="__main__":

    n = NumberOne()

    m = NumberTwo()

    print(m.list_of)
```

I would expect `print(m.list_of)` to return `['item1', 'item2', 'next']`, instead of `['item1', 'item2', 'next', 'next']`

I'm not sure whats causing this, can probably find a work around, but would rather understand whats going on.

Comment: Two independent objects whose `list_of` attributes both reference the *same* list.

Comment: You need to be careful with mutable default arguments. [See Also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument). This is causing the surprising effect In your code that: `m.list_of is n.list_of`

Comment: ok so my options are 

a) use a copy OR b) use a tuple and convert to a list in each sub